# How to install clickhouse under normal user permissions

Tags: installation, permissions, sudo, clickhouse

How to install clickhouse under normal user permissions.
Sudo asked me for root password。but i don't know the root password

Comment: I think you need just run ClickHouse in Docker: *docker run -d --name ch -p 8123:8123 -p 9000:9000 --ulimit nofile=262144:262144 yandex/clickhouse-server*. And then: *docker exec ch bash*

Comment: see for details: https://hub.docker.com/r/yandex/clickhouse-server/

Answer (score 1):

not related to CH.
Package management requires root privs. If your company does not provide a root password probably it's for a reason.

You can use CH without installation. Download server binary or tar with binary
https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/releases

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/releases/download/v20.13.1.5343-testing/clickhouse-common-static-20.13.1.5343.tgz

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/releases/download/v20.13.1.5343-testing/clickhouse-client-20.13.1.5343.tgz

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/releases/download/v20.13.1.5343-testing/clickhouse-server-20.13.1.5343.tgz